# change image programmatically in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created image button programmatically and set the image

```
  img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starred);
    img.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(28,28));
```

i want to change image when user click on image

```
         img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    try
      {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Job_Description.this);
     builder.setTitle("Save this Job ?");
   // builder.setMessage("whould You like to save job");
     builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
     {
                                                   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.starapplied);

                     }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled.
                              dialog.cancel();
                          }
                        });
                    builder.show();
         }catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.d("Image clicked", e.toString());
         }
        }
    });
```

am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: in the onClick() method just set to the image you want as you are doing previously. 
like, onClcik(view){ img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image); try{//your code //} }

Comment: If any answer was helpful please mark as correct answer to close the thread ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting any image `onClick` of your image. You are just pushing the dialog. If you want to change image after `onClick` of the `ImageView`
then add this line  in your `onClick` method

`imageView.setImageResource(resId);`

Comment: sorry for not mention, but we try      'img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.starapplied));'    and 'imageView.setImageResource(resId);'

Comment: ' public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
     {
                                                   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.starapplied);

                     }'

Comment: img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starred); also apply imageView.setImageResource(resId);

Comment: set either backgound or resource any one of them for beofre and after click otherwise one view is overlap another..

Comment: i applied 'img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starred)' and 'img.setImageResource(resId)' both but can't solve my problem, i am new android developer..

Comment: working +1.... Actually in imagebutton if you want to change image src this will work..

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.parking_map);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```